# How do I select one row over another conditionally in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated field which will choose one row over the other based on certain set of conditions. This is what my data looks like

```
           id   month   window         deviation2
     0102G116   0       
     0102G116   1                      NO
     0102G116   6       In Window   
     0102G116   12                     NO
     0102G116   12                     NO
     0102G116   18                     NO
     0102G116   24                     NO
     0114G101   0       
     0114G101   1       In Window   
     0114G101   6       In Window   
     0114G101   12      Out of Window  NO
     0114G101   12      Out of Window  YES
     0114G101   18      In Window   
     0114G101   24      In Window   
     0114G101   36      Out of Window  YES
     0116G103   0       
     0116G103   1       In Window   
     0116G103   6       In Window   
     0116G103   12                     NO
     0116G103   12                     NO
     0116G103   18      In Window   
     0116G103   24      In Window   
     0116G103   36      In Window   
     0116G103   48      In Window   
     0116G104   0       
     0116G104   1       In Window   
     0116G104   6       In Window   
     0116G104   12      Out of Window  NO
     0116G104   12      Out of Window  YES
     0116G104   18      In Window   
     0116G104   24      In Window   
     0116G104   36      In Window   
     0116G104   48      In Window
```

Everything which is "in window" in the WINDOW column will have blank/null as their corressponding value in deviation. Everything which is out of window can have 3 possible outcomes. YES, NO or NULL (NULL happens when it is "in window" in the WINDOW column). Also, if there is no entry in WINDOW column, it will be NO in deviation column.

However, there can be only one row for each id, month combination and there are cases here where there are more than one row. In such situation the logic to choose between them is

```
     if deviation = yes and deviation = no, then deviation = yes. (So only one row should stay with "Yes" as the deviation value)
     if deviation = no and deviation = no, then deviation = no. (So only one row should stay with "No" as the deviation value)
     if deviation = null and deviation = no/yes then deviation = null (So only one row should stay with "Null" as the deviation value)
```

I have been unable to come up with a calculated column like deviation2 which will apply the above logic. In such case the output would look like

```
          id    month   window         deviation
     0102G116   0       
     0102G116   1                      NO
     0102G116   6       In Window   
     0102G116   12                     NO
     0102G116   18                     NO
     0102G116   24                     NO
     0114G101   0       
     0114G101   1       In Window   
     0114G101   6       In Window   
     0114G101   12      Out of Window  YES
     0114G101   18      In Window   
     0114G101   24      In Window   
     0114G101   36      Out of Window  YES
     0116G103   0       
     0116G103   1       In Window   
     0116G103   6       In Window   
     0116G103   12                     NO
     0116G103   18      In Window   
     0116G103   24      In Window   
     0116G103   36      In Window   
     0116G103   48      In Window   
     0116G104   0       
     0116G104   1       In Window   
     0116G104   6       In Window   
     0116G104   12      Out of Window  YES
     0116G104   18      In Window   
     0116G104   24      In Window   
     0116G104   36      In Window   
     0116G104   48      In Window
```

I have tried to be as detailed as possible, let me know if there's anything else I can do to bring more clarity.

Thank you for all your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is a good situation to use level of detail calculations (LOD). You are working with values that are computed at different levels of detail.

I'm going to assume you convert your string fields ("YES", "NO") into boolean fields (TRUE, FALSE) since it makes things a bit simpler. Not strictly necessary though. Given that, a formula along the following lines should work:

```
{ FIXED id, month : if count(deviation) = count(1) then max(deviation) end}
```

For each combination of id and month, the above calc returns null if any row has a null deviation. If all rows have a non-null value for deviation, then it evaluates to the maximum value, where TRUE is considered > FALSE. (So if any data row has a true deviation, then the formula returns true.)